# Installing extensions of a program that is installed twice

Tags: installation, python, environment-variables, path

I have Python installed twice in my computer. The `python.exe` file is located once under `C:\Python34` and again under `C:\Anaconda3`.
The first was installed through the standard Python installation, while the second through the Anaconda package which has the same standard Python plus some extra extensions. Both Python versions are 3.4.4.
Now, I was trying to install a Python library/extension (e.g. facebook library). This can be done by typing this in the command line:

```
pip install facebook
```

The `pip` keyword is a Python module that simplifies the installation of external libraries. In my case this installs the facebook library only for the standard Python, not for the Anaconda Python. 
What I would like instead is to install the library for the Anaconda Python. I can tell because the facebook library is being created under `C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages`, but not under `C:\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages`.

So, why is the library choosing the first Python, and ignoring the second? And, how can I control this behavior?

**EDIT**: Maybe it's worth mentioning that both `C:\Python34` and `C:\Anaconda3` are included in the Path environment variables. `C:\Python34` comes first, and then `C:\Anaconda3`, but I also tried to put `C:\Anaconda3` first, and then `C:\Python34` and tried the installation again. However, the library was again installed in the standard Python. 
Also, `pip` is installed in both Pythons.

Comment: Which folder appears in the path first (from the left)? You are likely invoking that instance of pip. check your python dirs to make sure they both have pip, and then try to call it with the full path to update each instance seperately. eg `c:\python34\...\pip.exe install facebook` and `c:\anaconda3\...\pip.exe install facebook`

Comment: @FrankThomas I added some edits to my question. I was trying to execute it via the full pip path, but there is no pip.exe file in there. I tried C:\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pip\__init__.py, but that didn't work either.

Comment: You could uninstall `python34` ;)

Comment: @DavidPostill, I know the solution - I don't know the reason :).

Comment: Are there any other environment variables that are python related?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So, why is the library choosing the first Python, and ignoring the second?

Most likely because `C:\Python34` precedes `C:\Anaconda3` in your PATH.

> And, how can I control this behavior?

Invoke Anaconda's pip, which should be located in `C:\Anaconda3\Scripts`.

Comment: Your answer is half-wrong because having `C:\Anaconda3` precede `C:\Python34` didn't fix the problem. Instead, having `C:\Anaconda3\Scripts` precede `C:\Python34\Scripts` did fix the problem.
Your answer is half-correct because invoking Anaconda's pip full path `C:\Anaconda\Scripts\pip.exe` in the command line also fixes the problem.